# INT and STR issue in data find from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to find data from my JSON, and return some of it's values. This apparently is giving me some issues between str/int and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Here is the data set:

```
data = {
    "ports": [
            {
                    "port": "A",
                    "sensor": 4,
                    "door": "pin0",
                    "lights": "pin3"
            },
            {
                    "port": "Q",
                    "sensor": 22,
                    "door": "pin2",
                    "lights": "pin44"
            }
    ]
}
```

And here is the code:

```
def detect(sens):
        for i in data:
                if i["sensor"] == sens:
                        print(i["port"])
                        print(i["door"])
                        print(i["lights"])
                        break
```

The error that it returns is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tester.py", line 45, in
detect
    if i["sensor"] == sens: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

As the numers are not within "", I figured they would be integers, but apparently not. I tried forcing them as such with int(4), but that also didn't seem to do it. Forcing the i["sensor"] as an interger with:   if int(i["sensor"]) == sens: also did nothing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: hey your i represents the list not dict. that why showing the error so please add another for loop for i so you get the dict

Comment: That's not JSON. It may have *come* from JSON, but it's been decoded into a ordinary Python data structure, which is all that matters for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate over `data["ports"]`, not `data` itself.

```
def detect(sens):
    for p in data["ports"]:
        if p["sensor"] == sens:
            print(p["port"])
            print(p["door"])
            print(p["lights"])
            break
```

Comment: Of course.... So simple. I can't believe I did not think of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def detect(sens): 
    lst = [value for key, value in data["ports"].items() if key == 
                                                             sens]
    print(lst)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `for i in data['ports']:` instead of `for i in data:`. Then function call `detect(22)` will then give you results you expect.
When you iterate `data` you work with "ports" key only.